# is there an open API for healthcare's medicaid / CHIP eligibility?

Tags: data.gov, government, api, medical, healthcare-finder-api

I'd like to make a healthcare website that would help customers find their healthcare plans easily.

How can I check if the user is eligible for medicaid, or CHIP or medicare? I know how to get the FPL, but I'm still confused.